# Dynamic column in jqgrid shows "Length of colNames <> colModel!"

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

Please anyone help me in fixing this. I am trying add dynamic column names and column models information from the php script named simple8.php and the data is obtaining from the simple7.php.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {

  var seq=  $('#sim').text();
  var seq= seq.replace(/[\“\”\″]/ig,'\"');
  var seq = jQuery.trim(seq);
  var title = $('#title_for_table').text();
  var title = jQuery.trim(title);

          $.ajax({
              url:"simple8.php"+seq,
              type: "POST",
              data: "",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                var ColN = data.colNames; 
                var ColM = data.colModel; 

    jQuery("#tableid").jqGrid({
      url: "simple7.php"+seq,
      datatype: "jsonstring",
      mtype: "POST",
      colNames: ColN,
      colModel: ColM,
      pager: '#pager',
      rowNum:50,
      rowList:[25,50,75,100],
      sortname: 'r1',
      sortorder: "asc",
      viewrecords: true,
      gridview: true,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      caption:title+" Search Results",
      loadComplete: function(reload) {
        jQuery("#tableid").trigger("reloadGrid");

      },

  }); 

  jQuery("#tableid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{add:false,edit:false,del:false});
  jQuery("#tableid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd','#pager',{caption: "Export",onClickButton: function () { //exportExcel($(this));
  ExportJQGridDataToExcel($(this),'file1.xls');
           },position:"last"
  });






              },
              error: function () {
                  alert("Error with AJAX callback");
              }
          });


  });
  </script>
```

the output of simple8.php is:

```
{"colNames":"['col','r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r4', 'r5', 'r6', 'r7', 'r8', 'r9', 'r10', 'r11']","colModel":"[{name:'col', index:'col', width:120},{name:'r1', index:'r1', width:120},{name:'r2', index:'r2', width:120},{name:'r3', index:'r3', width:120},{name:'r4', index:'r4', width:120},{name:'r5', index:'r5', width:120},{name:'r6', index:'r6', width:120},{name:'r7', index:'r7', width:120},{name:'r8', index:'r8', width:120},{name:'r9', index:'r9', width:120},{name:'r10', index:'r10', width:120},{name:'r11', index:'r11', width:120}]"}
```

and simple7.php gives:

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":4,"rows":[{"id":null,"cell":["Chaffa","R","R","C","A","C","A","A","T","T","G","G"]},{"id":null,"cell":["CSG8962","R","R","Y","A","C","A","A","T","T","G","S"]},{"id":null,"cell":["DCP92_3","G","A","C","M","C","A","A","T","W","G","G"]},{"id":null,"cell":["DigVijay","R","A","C","A","C","A","A","T","T","G","S"]}]}
```

Please let me know where i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `colNames` is a **string** instead of array of items. The same one can say about `colModel`. You should change the data returned from the server to use only `"` instead of `'` and then use `colNames: $.parseJSON(ColN)` and `colModel: $.parseJSON(ColM)` instead of `colNames: ColN, colModel: ColM`. Without replacing `'` with `"` you will have error in parsing of JSON in `$.parseJSON`.